# What exactly are the data augmentation experimental Keras' layers doing?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, image-classification, image-preprocessing, data-augmentation

From what I gathered, data augmentation consists in increasing your number of instances in your dataset by applying some transfromations. Let's say I want to classify images. If I apply a random rotation to every image in a data set containing $n$ images, I will obtain a new dataset with $2n$ images, $n$ pairs of the original image plus it's random-rotated counterpart.

Assuming this is true, I don't understand what keras experimental layers related to data augmentation are doing.

Take `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation` . In the [image classification tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#data_augmentation), it puts this layer inside the Sequential model like this:

```
model = Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal", 
                                                 input_shape=(img_height, 
                                                              img_width,
                                                              3)),
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
```

This is already kind of weird because a layer produces an output from an input (obviously) but it doesn't duplicate the image. Anyway, I decided to check this in the documentation, and, in effect, this is what is happening.

```
Init signature: layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(*args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
Randomly rotate each image.

By default, random rotations are only applied during training.
At inference time, the layer does nothing. If you need to apply random
rotations at inference time, set `training` to True when calling the layer.

Input shape:
  4D tensor with shape:
  `(samples, height, width, channels)`, data_format='channels_last'.

Output shape:
  4D tensor with shape:
  `(samples, height, width, channels)`, data_format='channels_last'.
```

Therefore, I understand that I'm just randomly rotating the image, that is, changing each image in the dataset, but I'm not doing any data augmentation. However, I find this would make no sense, otherwise they wouldn't mention this as a data augmentation procedure. So what am I missing?

Comment: For every epoch you train, all images are used once, so for each epoch that passes, your model is trained on another set of `n` augmented images. So if you train for 10 epochs, you have trained on *10n* images (*9n* of which are augmented from the original). But yeah, if you were to only train for one epoch, I guess it would not make much sense to have that layer there.

Comment: @Marcus Oh, that's true I totally missed that, thank you!. However, do I ever get to train the original image? As the layer is always in the model I guess I never train the original one

Comment: I cannot find any information in regards to whether Tensorflow is clever enough to use the original images once and once only, but if I were to guess I would assume that your original images are never used. However, the similarity between your validation images and your augmented images should, when the number of epochs become large, become very similar to that of your original images.

Comment: @CMB I think you should make these two comments into an answer. They do answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look into the code you can figure what's exactly happening.

Take `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation` for example

```
def call(self, inputs, training=True):
  ...
  def random_flipped_inputs():
    flipped_outputs = inputs
    if self.horizontal:
      flipped_outputs = image_ops.random_flip_left_right(flipped_outputs,
                                                         self.seed)
    ...
    return flipped_outputs
```

You will see it's gonna to `random_flip_left_right` on your input images, and the comments inside it is

```
"""Randomly flip an image horizontally (left to right).
With a 1 in 2 chance, outputs the contents of `image` flipped along the
second dimension, which is `width`.  Otherwise output the image as-is.
When passing a batch of images, each image will be randomly flipped
independent of other images."""
Example usage:
...
>>> images = np.array(
... [
...     [[[1], [2]], [[3], [4]]],
...     [[[5], [6]], [[7], [8]]]
... ])
>>> tf.image.random_flip_left_right(images, 6).numpy().tolist()
[[[[2], [1]], [[4], [3]]], [[[5], [6]], [[7], [8]]]]
```

So basically what it is doing is each image will have a 50% chance to horizontally be flipped, so if you have 10 epochs, image_1 will have possibility to be [original, flipped, original, flipped, ...], and so on so forth to other images. Seeing from the outside would identify we have 10 different datasets(particularly on multiple data augmentation).